# How to re-install nuget package that's already in the solution's packages directory?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, asp.net-mvc-4, nuget, package

### Background / History

- I have a solution that contains an MVC4 project.
- I downloaded a nuget package (specifically the dotLess package). This added a packages folder to my solution directory which includes dotless (it's still there).
- I then removed the MVC4 project to start fresh and added a new project with the same name.

Normally, I would just reinstall the package. However, this seems to require the Nuget server and a connection to the internet. This is fine, except currently my development machine is without internet.

### Question

Since I can see the folder with the package file in my solution's "packages" directory, is there any way I can add it to the project without having to round-trip via the internet?

Answer (score 2):

Another option would be to setup a local nuget gallery for your offline access to the packages

http://www.codecapers.com/post/How-to-Set-Up-a-Local-NuGet-Gallery.aspx

Comment: I like this as a way of keeping private packages that you can't share with the world for some reason. Good for base packages for internal dev, etc. And in conjunction with the local caching stuff, you can make the entire team work even when they're on the beach (I'm kidding).

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this from Scott Hanselman? http://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowToAccessNuGetWhenNuGetorgIsDownOrYoureOnAPlane.aspx

In brief he suggests that since NuGet caches stuff on your local hard drive, you should tell it to point there.

I used this when a proxy was preventing me from connecting to the internet and it worked nicely!

Comment: This is interesting; however, what I have currently is just the [SolutionName]\packages directory. Can I point nuget to this location to reinstall a package to the same location? It could work, just seems like it might not be the best idea (though I can't necessarily support that).

Comment: Yes I think in your case you will have to point nuget to this location  and it should work fine as your local cache, since you don't have anything at `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\NuGet\Cache`

Answer (score -1):

If I understand you correctly and you know the correct version number then you could try adding the following to packages.config and see if it's picked up correctly.

```
  <package id="dotless" version="1.3.1.0" />
```

Comment: I feel this is a quick way to do if you want for just this project. And you would have to run update-package -reinstall from package manager console to re-add the assets for the package to the project.

Comment: A combination of this answer and Deepak's comment will I think be the final solution. I will see tomorrow if I can add the line and run update-package -reinstall from the package manager without it needing the internet.

Comment: i was trying it and had to give source as well from my local box where it should look for re-installing packages.
update-package -reinstall -source "C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\NuGet\Cache"

Answer (score -1):

This is perhaps not an ideal answer but whenever I loose connection with a Nuget package in Visual Studio I usually turn to the Nuget Console and reinstall from there, after that all connections are restored.  Which in your case would be something like:

> PM> Install-Package dotless

Anyway, maybe I´m misunderstanding your issue  ;)
Regards!

Comment: Yes. Because I'm not connected to the internet at this point as I mention in the post. So, running this command results in an error about connectivity to nuget.